# Karate tests: how to pass value from 1 response to another request

Tags: karate

I'm creating new scenario where I create offer and I want to get the offer ID to another request.
I can print the offer ID but I have a problem with pass this ID to another scenario.
It looks like this:

```
`  Scenario: create offer
    Given url 'url/to_create_offer'
    When request readJsonAsBody
    And method POST
    Then status 202
    * def offerId = response.id
    Then print offerId

  Scenario: get offer
    Given url 'url/to_get_created_offer/here_should_be_offer_id'
    And method GET
    Then status 200`
```

I have tried this example but it not works for me:

```
`* url 'https://httpbin.org'
* path 'anything'
* request {"myKey":"myValue"}
* method get
* status 200

* def myResult = response.json.myKey
* path 'anything/' + myResult
* method get
* status 200`
```

or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: the second example works fine for me. you can also try this example: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-todo/blob/main/src/test/java/app/api/simple/jsonplace.feature - if still stuck, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue